# How to align center the flex-start items?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I know why it isn't possible to align center in flex wrapped container with flex-started items.
As you know, if you try to whatever you do, it would make right space.
What I know is that I could align those items to center using css-grid and media queries so far.
However, I'm looking for another way, less annoying way.

For example, the structure is like below.

```html
<Container>
    <Item/>
    <Item/>
    <Item/>
    <Item/>
    <Item/>
    <Item/>
    <Item/>
    <Item/>
</Container>
```

If you have any of ideas and tips, please let me know.
Thank you.

---

I think I need to add more detail.
It should be looked like this.

```html
---- [] [] [] [] [] ---- 1row
---- [] []          ---- 2row
same spaces on right and left sides
```

Comment: do you want to align item vertically or horizontally using flexbox?

Comment: let's use `align-items : center`

Comment: vertically and horizontally it should be on center.

Answer (score 1):

By using flex you can easily make items align center with less code. `align-items: center;` will help you to make center your element into middle of your screen.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <p>Item 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not what I'm looking for.
I edited my question cause I think I made you misunderstand what my question is.

Comment: to keep some space for left and right you need to use margin or padding. and align-item center will keep your text middle base on your viewport size

Comment: I know, but the problem is if I use flexbox and align-item center, last two items won't be flex-start, but the center. So, it's different from my expectation.